# How to increase PHP file size limits on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, php, web-server

When I upload the file in phpmyadmin this problem appears `413 Request Entity Too Large`
my configure `php.ini`

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
memory_limit = 256M
```

I have NGINX server with FASTCGI php-fpm 127.0.0.1:9000 which php.ini is under /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

I increased upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini

The Fastcgi params is like this

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M"

client_max_body_size 100M;
```

I restarted php-fpm and nginx, But the problem is still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just I have change `fastcgi_pass` to the right source

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/163014821416069.sock/socket;

To

fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes from nginx, in your nginx.conf set the following value:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Obviously if you want a bigger file size then 100MB, make this value higher

---

You can read more about client_max_body_size in the nginx documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: I've done this before and now I've tried again but it failed

Comment: @Thaerz Which context are you using it in?  `http`? Try `server`.

Comment: @Wesley   Context: http, server, location